# how extract into model from json api

Tags: java, json, parsing

i got a json like this im not sure how should i start to get this json into a arraylists of my Class.
This is a sample i got but i have like 10-20 nodes like this.Not sure how to start. I am not sure is **JsonArray** will be useful since nothing got seperate with **[ ]** and everything are delimited with comma. Any help will be appreciate Thanks.

```
{
    "1": {
        "1": {
            "0": {
                "id": 23,
                "ex_id": "58",
                "rate": 2.44,
                "type": 1,
                "provid_ids": 250,
                "ratehold": 120
            },
            "href": "link1",
            "province_en": "pren",
            "href_fr": "link1fr",
            "province_fr": "prfr"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": {
                "id": 44,
                "ex_id": "999",
                "rate": 4.44,
                "type": 1,
                "provid_ids": 118,
                "ratehold": 902
            },
            "href": "link1",
            "province_en": "pren",
            "href_fr": "link1fr",
            "province_fr": "prfr"
        }
    }

}
```

This my Model

```
public class Rate {

    private String id;
    private String ex_id;
    private String rate;
    private String type;
    private String provid_ids;
    private String ratehold;

...

}

public class Link {

    private String href;
    private String province_en;
    private String href_fr;
    private String province_fr;

...

}
```

Comment: the top block of code is very difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON does not contain **[ ]**, and hence not in the form of an array.

You should use a JSON Object here.

You can iterate through JSON objects using the keys():

```
Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();
 while (keys.hasNext()) {
 Object key = keys.next();
 JSONObject value = jsonObject.getJSONObject((String) key); 
 }
```